# How to choose a particular folder to copy folder structure from to a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy the file structure of D:\ into C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\test.txt

When I run this, it just copies the contents of the current folder it is in. But I want it to copy files that are in D:\  What am I doing wrong?  If I put in D:> it does nothing.

```
D:\
dir > C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\test.txt
```

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type `DIR /?` to read the help file for the `DIR` command.  It will explain all the options you can use to accomplish your task.

Comment: Yes, the /? says drive: path


But the drive and the path are the same.  It's D:\


I tried putting in D:\ D:\ and dir D:\  neither of them generates the text file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `CD` :

```
CD D:\
dir > C:\Users\user1\Downloads\test\test.txt
```

Comment: No, this is wrong! It is either `D:` plus `cd D:\ `, or just `cd /D "D:\"`! You need to learn that `cd` without the `/D` option does *not* change the drive! Anyway, the simplest approach is to use only a single line for everything: `dir "D:\" > "%UserProfile%\Downloads\test\test.txt"`…

Comment: Ah ok, better solution. Thank you.